# Connectivity issue from Excel 2010 to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

We are using Excel 2010 and was running in Window XP. Connectivity with SharePoint was good.
Recently our environment got migrated from XP to Windows 7. Until that point we are seeing the following challenges:

1. Excel is not connecting with the SharePoint.

   Getting the following error:

   > A connection to the SharePoint site cannot be established. To synchronize or refresh your table you must be able to connect to the SharePoint site.
2. Sorting or selecting any name from the dropdown is not working
   properly.

Any help to resolve this.

Comment: Is you Sharepoint Site in "Trusted sites" zone in internet explorer?